# in angularJS how to format Date()

Tags: angularjs, date

Any help on formatting /date()/ in angularjs 1.6.

Want to format it in HTML not inside the javascript controller.

Have tried angular-relative-date.

Comment: have you tried Angular Date filter

Answer (score -1):

Got it working using this code

```
{{order.CreatedOn.replace('/Date(','').replace(')/','') | date | relativeDate}}
```